# Array of strings converted into numbers and sorted

Tags: c++, debugging

As a beginner I am trying to input one digit numbers in word form, but sort and display them as numbers.

On inputting :

seven
three
five
one
nil

the output is

0
1
3
5
7
How can i stop 0 from displaying and from being populated in num array in first place?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#define n 5
using namespace std;

string words[n];
int nums[n],size;
void input(){
     cout<<"Enter in word form, the numbers to be sorted\n";
     for( int i = 0;  ; i++){
         cin >> words[i];
         if( words[i] == "nil" )
             break;
     }
     size = sizeof words/sizeof(string);
}
void convert(){
     for( int i = 0; words[i]!= "nil" ; i++ ){
          if ( words[i] == "one" )
             nums[i] = 1;
          //
          else 
               cout<<"Wrong input\n";
     }
}
void sort(){
     sort(nums, nums + size);
     for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
         cout<< nums[i]<<endl;
}
int main(){
    input();
    convert();
    sort();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine, I erred at length of words..to remove element nil (used as sentinel) from consideration of sort i had to reduce size by 1 . This code works just fine and the way it is intended to.

```
 //headers and std

string words[n];
int nums[n],size;
void input(){
     cout<<"Enter in word form, the numbers to be sorted\n";
     for( int i = 0; ; i++){
         cin >> words[i];
         if ( words[i] == "nil" )
            break;
     }
     size = sizeof words/sizeof(string) - 1;//one for nil
}
void convert(){
     for( int i = 0; words[i]!= "nil" ; i++ ){
          if ( words[i] == "one" )
              nums[i] = 1;
          else if ( words[i] ==  "two") 
           //
     }
}
void sort(){
     sort(nums, nums + size);
     for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
         cout<< nums[i]<<endl;
}
int main(){
    // 
}
```

Comment: Most likely, you are overwritting the bounds of allocated array. Also, why do you fill the array from `1` index and not `0`? In C and C++ `0` is the first index. The valid index range is `0` to `N-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

words is an array of size n, which means the valid indices for words are from 0 to  n - 1. Your code uses indices 1 to n. So this

```
string words[n];
...
for( int i = 1;  ; i++){
...
for( int i = 1; i<= n; i++ ){
      if ( words[i] == "one" )
...
for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
     cout<< nums[i]<<endl;
```

should be this

```
string words[n];
...
for( int i = 0;  ; i++){
...
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
      if ( words[i] == "one" )
...
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
     cout<< nums[i]<<endl;
```

In C++ arrays start at **zero**.

Comment: Thanks, the segmentation fault error is now removed. Thanks everyone else too. Please look at the edited program and related question.

Comment: @ShivaniDhanked Editing a question is intended to provide additional information or correct errors, not to change it completely. Now anybody reading these answers does not know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `void input()`, there should no `i++` out of `for` ?And `i` should start from 0?
2. The fatal error in `void convert()` `for( int i = 1; i<= n; i++ )`. since you define words as `string[5]`, it should start from `words[0]` to `words[4]`. So is `nums[5]`.

Correction code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#define n 5
using namespace std;

string words[n] = {};
int nums[n];
void input(){
     cout<<"Enter in word form, the numbers to be sorted\n";
     for( int i = 0; i<n ; i++){
         cin >> words[i];
         if( words[i] == "nil" )
             break;
         //i++;
     }
}
void convert(){
     cout<<"n = "<<n<<endl;
     for( int i = 0; i<n; i++ ){
          if ( words[i] == "one" )
             nums[i] = 1;
          else if ( words[i] ==  "two")
             nums[i] = 2;
          else if ( words[i] == "three")
             nums[i] = 3;
          else if ( words[i] == "four")
             nums[i] = 4;
          else if ( words[i] == "five")
             nums[i] = 5;
          else if ( words[i] ==  "six")
             nums[i] = 6;
          else if ( words[i] ==  "seven")
             nums[i] = 7;
          else if ( words[i] == "eight")
             nums[i] = 8;
          else if ( words[i] ==  "nine")
             nums[i] = 9;
          else if ( words[i] ==  "zero")
             nums[i] = 0;
          else
               cout<<"Wrong input\n";
     }
}
void sort(){
     sort(nums, nums + n);
     for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
         cout<< nums[i]<<endl;
}
int main(){
    input();
    cout <<"after input" <<endl;
    convert();
    cout <<"after convert" <<endl;
    sort();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```